# C Macro for replacing array subscript

Tags: c

I want to replace array subscript of a C code with a call to a hash function. Is it possible to do this using a C macro?

This is an old code and it is very difficult to make changes to it. It will be very helpful, if I could just use a macro and a hash function instead of changing the actual code.

```
int array[1000];
// I want to define a macro such that array[idx] will be replaced with 
// array[hash(idx)] and then define a function called hash(idx) which
// will return an integer within the bounds of the array (0..999)
int main()
{
  int input;
  scanf("%d", &input);
  array[input] = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you want. Could you populate a second array with results of the hash?

Comment: In a macro call, you would need to use parentheses instead of square brackets. For example, you could have a statement similar to `ARRAY(input) = 1;` and the macro could be defined as `#define ARRAY(i) (array[hash(i)])`. So then `ARRAY(input) = 1;` would expand to `(array[hash(input)]) = 1;`.

Comment: You could write a macro that replaces `input` with a hash call, but I guess that's not what you want? You rather want `[anything]` to be replaced with `[hash(anything)]`, correct?

Comment: @Lundin Yes that is correct.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for the suggestion. But that would need me to change the existing which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Okay, no can do then, I think. You'd have to pass on the index to a macro somehow, but there is no way to write a macro that uses [] rather than ().

Comment: @Lundin I see, thanks anyways.

Comment: @billpg I am not sure how populating a second array would help. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You could use `#define input hash(input)`, but that would be quite limited, not to mention confusing. It would break in your `scanf` call for example, because `&input` would expand to `&hash(input)`, which is invalid (unless `hash(x)` is a function-like macro that expands to an *lvalue*). In short: don't do this!

Comment: True, I suppose this is not a good idea as well.

Comment: You could use any reasonable language you know and like to parse the old sources and replace each indexed access by the corresponding hashed access. The output of this script or program will still be C and has to be complied, of course. But as others commented, the preprocessor can't do this.

Comment: Whenever you have to choose between making a good change (refactor) or a bad change (hack with macros), pick the good change. This is what separates good software developers from bad ones.

Comment: you can switch to c++, declare the `array` as a class and define a custom [] operator within it.